# How can I invert the selection for killing windows in Tmux?

Tags: tmux, window

Sometimes I want to kill all windows besides the current one (or the one selected using `-t`).

Instead of killing each window using `kill-window -t <window>` how can I invert the selection, so that I kill every window except the current one (or the one selected using `-t`)?

I've tried `kill-window -t[!1]` or `kill-window -t!(1)` to kill all windows except window 1, but it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a key binding to do this:

- `new-session -d -s foo` creates a new session
- `move-window -t foo:` moves the current window to the new session
- `rename-session old` give this session the name `old` so we can kill it later
- `switch-client -t foo:` switch to the new session
- `kill-window -t 1` kill the first window that was created by default
- `kill-session -t old:` kills the old session (and all remaining windows)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know the approaches I have tried failed? `man tmux` says it should support `fnmatch(3)`, and `[!1]` is a `glob(7)` matching anything but `1`

Comment: Is there any reason you append a “:” to sessions as in `-t old:`? Wouldn’t `-t old` work just as fine?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to automatically rename the new session like the old one? Indeed, I need a variable holding the old name for this to work.

Comment: Just because it could match more than one window does not mean that it will operate on more than one. AFAIK the target is always for one session/window/pane.

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to save the session name in a variable during a key binding?

Comment: I think it's easier if you write a shell script for that - you can bind it from tmux with `run-shell`

Comment: do you know why I can't expand shell variables as in `run-shell "new='#S'; echo $new"`? Here $new is expanded to the empty string, not the session name.

Comment: Please ask a new question ...